# Can you copy an area of weight painted vertecies and paste it onto another surface?(v3.0.0)

Tags: weight-painting

I have an example image underneath this text.

So, let's say I want to copy al these painted vertecies that you can see in the image and paste them onto another surface, in my case another model. Is there a way to copy-paste all these vertecies at the same time onto another surface?

I'm a beginner in Blender, so a well-described explanation would be nice.

Thank you in advance.

[image]